# PowerBI access to Azure SQL Database(PaaS)

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database as PaaS Solution. I have some network access rules in the Firewall of Azure SQL Database. I want to connect PowerBI to Azure SQL Database securely. I had checked the option of **Allow access to Azure Services** in Firewall.  However, it also makes the database visible to any component deployed within Azure, such as a virtual machine.

Are there any methods to use Azure SQL Database(Paas) securely from PowerBI?

Comment: You could whitelist the client IP in the SQL database firewall.

Comment: Hi @abhishek gaikwad， If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to set **Allow access to Azure Services** in Azure SQL database firewall, you could add the current client IP address to the firewall.

It will only allow your current client/computer to access the Azure SQL.

Then you could access the Azure SQL database from PowerBI securely.